# Can the 'del' function in python remove elements from two lists at the same time?

Tags: python, list

So I have a loop that roughly looks like this:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
for i in range(len(something[i])):
     aux=[]
     for j in range(len(something_else)):
         aux.append(do_stuff(j))
         aux.append(do_more_stuff(j))
     list1.append(aux)
     list2.append([i,aux])
```

Basically `list1` looks like (curly braces for ease) (1)

```
[ {['hello', 1],['python', 0]} , {['is', 1],['very', 0]} ,{['cool', 1]} ]
```

and `list2` like

```
[ [0, {['hello', 1], ['python', 0]}], [1, {['is', 1],['very', 0]}], [2, {['cool', 1]}] ]
```

Now I want to remove the sublists from `list2` that have a 1 and store it in another variable `list3` as follows (2)

```
list3=list2.copy() #I want to keep both lists
for term in list3:
    for i in list(reversed(range(len(term[1])))): #this way it doesn't delete and skip terms
        if term[1][i][1]==1:
           del term[1][i]
```

this should yield `list3` as

```
[ [0, {['python', 0]}], [1, {['very', 0]}], [2, {}] ]
```

Everything works perfectly fine, but the strange thing is that the process in (2) **also** changes `list1`. If you print `list1` before the loop in (2) you get (1), but if you print `list1` after deleting the terms in `list3` (which remember was a copy of `list2`) suddenly you get:

```
[ {['python', 0]}, {['very', 0]}, {}]
```

as if we had performed the operation (2) on `list1`.

How can this be possible? Is it because `list1` and `list2` were created in the same loop? Even if I deleted the terms from a copy of `list2` instead of `list2` itself? Do the terms appended to `aux` inside the first loop have memory and are deleted everywhere? Any help?

Comment: you add the same element `aux` to both `list1` and `list2` - but it doesn't add copied but only reference to the same place in memory. If you later remove something then it removes from boths - because both have reference to the same place in memory. You would have to add `aux.copy()` to one of list.

Comment: run code on http://pythontutor.com/ and it will shows you how python keep lists in memory - you will see two arrows to the same list `aux`.

Comment: if you use nested lists/dictionares - list inside list - then you may need deep copy - ie. `import copy` `list3 = copy.deepcopy(list2)`

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation and recommendations, will take a look